# Composer - Windows installer is stuck

Tags: php, error-handling, composer-php

I'm using Windows 10, installed XAMPP 3.2.2 with PHP 5.6.x

I tried to install Composer via the exe, but whenever I click [Next](https://i.imgur.com/Jjq9W0y.png), the setup is stuck at [Checking your command-line PHP](https://i.imgur.com/SGBfhvj.png).

Yes, in the file `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` I removed the `;` from the beginning of `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

Yet the installer is still stuck on [this screen](https://i.imgur.com/SGBfhvj.png).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you added php to your `$_PATH` variable?

Comment: Probably not, since I didn't know about this. How do I do that?

Comment: Since I couldn't find `$_PATH` in `php.ini`, I thought it might have to do something with Windows's environment variables. I looked up for the Path value, and indeed there was no reference to `C;\xampp\php`, so I added one. Though, Composer's installer still produced the same problem.

Comment: I'd probably give reinstalling XAMPP a go

Comment: You were right. I reinstalled XAMPP and the Composer installer worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an awnser, you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling XAMPP, there might have been something that went wrong with the PHP installation.

Answer (score 10):

In my case it turned out that the check script  was just stuck in the debugger :)

Comment: Thank you, in my case it was PhpStorm with open xDebug listener